# change current page location with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I may be using a poor structure, but I have a reactjs `jsx` file that renders a form for new / edit of a resource. The router sends the same file if the path is either `mysite.com/myresource/edit/{id}` or `mysite.com/myresource/new` depending on the use.

If the form is submitted and it's on the `new` path, it will create a resource via an ajax API `POST` call and it'll update using a `PUT` if it's on the `edit` path.

My question is what do I do after the `POST`? I want to redirect the user to the `myresource/edit/{id}` with the new ID returned from the successful `POST` operation, but I am not sure how to do that with react-router. Would I just use a javascript `window.location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With react-router you can use `props.history.push('/myresource/edit/{id}')`

Doc: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history